# How to do error handling in protractor when errors like element not found, element not intractable,WebDriverError: unknown error occur

Tags: protractor, cucumberjs

I have executing some protractor script in a function and that function is calling in a for loop.So if any of the error occurring like element not found, element not intractable,WebDriverError: unknown error occur: Element is not clickable, then i need to skip for that loop count and need to execute next loop count.I have tried with isPresent(),isDisplayed() for catching the error but its not working then i tried below code for that.

```
 for(i=0; i<count; i++){   
   post(post_details[i].MediaUrl,post_details[i].CallToActionType,post_details[i].LPAID,post_details[i].CallToActionUrl);
  } 
 post((MediaUrl,CallToActionType,LPAID,CallToActionUrl){
  element(by.css(locators.locator_post_description)).sendKeys(Summary).then (function(){
    if(MediaUrl!=null){
       var path = require('path');
       var type=MediaUrl.split("/"); 
       var fileToUpload = '../files/' + (type[type.length-1]) ;
       var absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
       browser.sleep(3000);
       element(by.css(locators.locator_post_img)).sendKeys(absolutePath);
       browser.sleep(6000);
      }
    if(CallToActionType!=null){
       browser.sleep(1000);
       element(by.css(locators.locator_post_eventPostButton)).click();
       browser.sleep(2000);
       element(by.cssContainingText(locators.locator_post_buttonType,CallToActionType)).click();
       browser.sleep(1000);
       element(by.css(locators.locator_post_eventPostButtonLInk)).sendKeys(CallToActionUrl);
     }
    element(by.xpath(locators.locator_post_publishBtn)).click().then (function(){
      browser.sleep(3000);
      updatedb(LPAID); 
    }); 
 },function(err) {
   console.log("no summary...."+err);
   return true;
 }); 
}
```

Here i am getting values(MediaUrl,CallToActionType,LPAID) form DB and i am checking its value is not null.By using the above code, i am able to catch the error associated with description element and then exiting from that loop count and executing next loop count.But i am not able to use this error catching method for image element,button type element,button link element.So how can i catch error(if any) associated with each of the locator elements and if error occurred, then to skip that loop count.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Protractor has inbuilt Expected Conditions using which with browser.wait() you can handle the your issues. Refer to below code and link:

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var button = $('#xyz');
var isClickable = EC.elementToBeClickable(button);

browser.get(URL);
browser.wait(isClickable, 5000); //wait for an element to become clickable
button.click();
```

Documentation - https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions